# Incorrect mapping values when using LinkedHashMap to a List

Tags: java

I am to initialize what is called an `LZWDictionary` to have an initial set of entries taken from the set of unique characters in a provided string.

Unique characters are added to a map as they are encountered in the provided input string, with an increasing index value (beginning at index 0). At the same time, the characters are added to a list. The indices associated with each dictionary entry in the map thus relate to their index (position) in the list.

Here is the code that I tried with comments on my thought process.

```
// Initialising map
map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// Initialising list
list = new ArrayList<>();
// Declaring String variable for holding character
String str;
// Declaring index variable for holding Value
int index;

// If block for checking empty string.
if (characters.length() == 0)
    // Throwing IllegealArgumentException if String is empty.
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input should not be empty!!!");
else {

    // Iterating over the String
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++) {
        // Taking particular character in the Iteration
        str = "" + characters.charAt(i);
        // Checking value of a particular character in the map
        if (map.get(str) == null) {

            // If not present in map, then add that to the map and list
            map.put(str, 1);
            list.add(str);
        }

        else {

            index = map.get(str);
            map.replace(str, index + 1);
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting a java.lang.AssertionError where the index value for "a" is not correct in map expected<0> but was <5>. The sample code is:

```
LZWDictionary act = new LZWDictionary("ababababa");
List<String> exp = Arrays.asList("a","b");
```

Comment: *FYI:* `str = "" + characters.charAt(i)` is better written as `str = characters.substring(i, i + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**@20191105: simplified the code by removing additional 'int' variable as suggested by @Andreas

---

So, the problem of your code is the duplicated handling of same input character (In case you only want to count the first encountered appearance).

Then as mentioned by @Andreas, the code should be changed as below for getting what you've described:

```
    // Declaring index variable for holding Value
    //int index = 0;
```

.

```
        // Iterating over the String
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++) {
            // Taking particular character in the Iteration
            str = "" + characters.charAt(i);
            // Checking value of a particular character in the map

            /*
             * if (map.get(str) == null) {
             * 
             * // If not present in map, then add that to the map and list map.put(str, 1);
             * list.add(str); }
             * 
             * else {
             * 
             * index = map.get(str); map.replace(str, index + 1); }
             */
            // If not present in map, then add that to the map and list map.put(str, 1);
            if (map.get(str) == null) {
                //map.put(str, index++);
                map.put(str, map.size());
                list.add(str);
            }
        }

    // Below is just for testing what has been put to the collections ... 
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Integer> e = it.next();
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " ; " + e.getValue());
    }

    for (String a: list) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need `index`, just use the list size: `map.put(str, list.size())` --- The current size *is* the index of the next element added.

Comment: It's true. I was just thinking to keep the code close to original version for allowing @Keeley to understand it easily. I've just revised it per your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code isn't at all what you described:

```
if (map.get(str) == null) {

    // If not present in map, then add that to the map and list
    map.put(str, 1);
    list.add(str);
}

else {

    index = map.get(str);
    map.replace(str, index + 1);
}
```

You expect input `"ababababa"` to return a list `[a, b]`, i.e. the unique characters, and a map with `{a: 0, b: 1}`, right? And input `"aaaabbbbbbbbbbbb"` should give the same result, right?

So the result list and result maps are only updated the ***first*** time a characters is seen, right?

Which means your code above shouldn't have an `else` clause. Get rid of it.

Also, the map is supposed to have the index of the unique character. But you have `map.put(str, 1)`. They can't all be at index 1, can they?

Re-think what you're doing.